# React native, I'm not able to navigate between screens

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am following the react navigation documentation. I did all the installations.
I'm using react native expo in the latest version (0.63).
When I create a screen or create a function from within app.tsx, I have the following problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36vla.png)

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please follow this guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/. The `navigation` is of `props` type. Hard to see your code anyway to determine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#property-renaming), you can do the following:

```
...
function HomeScreen({ navigation }: { navigation: any} {
...
```

Comment: Why not follow the [react navigation typescript documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-screens) as `manishg` already pointed out?